# Error when installing WampServer

Tags: installation, wampserver

hi i am installing wampserver3 addon php 7.0.13 in my computer. Every time i am trying to install i got the following error:-

"The installation folder chosen (%1) in not that of the Wampserver.

Select the installation folder of wampserver."

i am also attaching a screenshot of the following error. kindly help me to resolve this issue.
[image]

thanks

Comment: this is software-related, not code-related. the php tag shouldn't even be included here. This, as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40580223/1

Comment: post on superuser instead http://superuser.com/

Comment: You have probably incorrectly selected the existing WAMPServer folder on the previous install dialog. If WAMPServer is in D:\wamp then select just the D: drive in the previous screen

Comment: If the my answer helped you, kindly accept it

Comment: Warning - Warning
The file indicated by "Looking for the latest version" is not the last "full install" version but the last file uploaded in the Wampserver project.
Most of the time, it is an addition of a PHP, MySQL, MariaDB or Apache version or an application like PhpMyAdmin.
If the term "addon", "apps", "update" appears in the file name, it is not a "full install" version.

Answer (score 48):

That's because you are **NOT** actually installing WampServer, but its PHP add-on.

If you used Google to find it, you probably downloaded and installed the **WampServer PHP add on** from [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/?source=typ_redirect). It would be named something like ***wampserver3_x64_addon_php7.0.13.exe***

[image]

[image]

[image]
This is **NOT** what you want.

You can get the actual WampServer install file from the [WampServer project site](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/)... which leads you to correct file on Source Forge. It would have a name like 
***wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.1***

---

**You want to get it from here:**

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/

[image]

Comment: You are indeed correct in what the issue is, but right now the download link on the wampServer project, points there (to the add on) it seems you need to manually navigate to files and find the version you want in sourceforge.

Comment: http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ This is the Secondary repository of Wampserver files. Those addons you showed above also correct and those can be found here as well. hope this would help.

Comment: @Karl, why would you share a link to a non-official source, when an official one exists?

Comment: @user919426 This is maintained by the official developers. © Dominique Ottello alias Otomatic - 2018. That's where you can find all the addons and latest software as a repository. You cant find other versions and addons on website.

Comment: I don't think the wampserver .exe exists on sourceforge any longer

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The response you are getting means that you are trying to install an incomplete version of WAMPSERVER. The incomplete version could be an addon or an extension. Visit wampserver website and click on the version you would like to download. Desist from using download latest button.

[Click here to download full version x64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.1.3_x64.exe/download)

[Click here to download full version x86](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.1.3_x86.exe/download)

Answer (score 0):

Because that green button is missleading and you have not downloaded thw Wamp Installer
but the Maria DB Addon (!) check again
You must navigate in sourceforge and select the latest wamp exe and clik on that link so the download will start

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got similar message in newer version of MySQL addon for Wampserver 3.3.3. I tried to install it just after Wampserver installation. After I started Wampserver for the first time, addon installation was successful

Comment: The first answer explains the issue very well. If you agree with the answer, you could upvote it and incase of any comments, post it there under that answer. This section is for posting a solution which has not been provided by someone already. Hope this helps you in your continuous interaction with stackoverflow.

Answer (score -3):

you probably downloaded the 64bit version when you need the 32bit version.