# The installation folder chosen is not that wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver

I have downloaded wamp server from this link http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/#download-wrapper
I have 64 bit operating system so I downloaded Wamp Server 64 bit.
Now I'm trying to install it but it shows an error during installation. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580223/error-when-installing-wampserver
 ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installing WampServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580223/error-when-installing-wampserver)

Comment: You can only install this `Adminer4.3.0 ADDON` if you have previously installed a FULL WAMPServer install. Did you install WAMPServer before this???

Comment: Install [wampserver3.0.6_x64](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/install/wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10.exe) first and then upgrade to [WAMPServer 3.0.8 from this link](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.8.exe)

Answer (score 3):

you probably are installing some update or add-on of the Wampserver other than the actual WAMP Server. To find it out, you can check the installer package file name. The WampServer setup file should be something like: 

**wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10.exe.**

You should find the wampserver version, apache version, mysql version, php version in the installer file. If you can see addon or update in the file name, it is not the Wampserver installer package. You need to go to the Wampserver website and download the right file and version, and re-install again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for install an addon package I needed to restart the operating system and later have running the wamp server.